# Single cosmosclient per account

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

When using the .NET SDK of Azure Cosmos v3, the recommendation is using a singleton CosmosClient.
However, this client requires the account details.
In our case, we are setting up a separate DB account in Azure (so physically a different resource) for each (B2B) tenant. Is it then still recommended having such singleton, or is a single instance per tenant still OK?

Bear in mind, tenants share the same application instance (and thus app memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos client instance is per account. You cannot create a single instance and have it connect to multiple accounts simultaneously.

Generally speaking, multi-tenant apps in the same application instance are designed to be tenant per container or tenant per partition key. Applications which use the Cosmos account as the tenant boundary are often only done when tenants have different replication regions or have other networking or other needs, such as security which can only be managed at the account level.

If this is not the case then I suggest you evaluate what your tenant boundary is. Tenant per account is an expensive option on a per tenant basis. It also has the highest operational overhead.

There is a really good presentation from the recent Cosmos DB Conf which does a really great job explaining how to design multi-tenant apps using Cosmos DB. Definitely worth watching, [From the trenches: Building an awesome multitenant SaaS with Cosmos DB and Azure](https://youtu.be/Tht_RV5QPJ0).

There is also another older talk that also talks about options for tenant boundaries which is also really good. The first 20 minutes is the multi-tenant part, [Mission-critical multi-tenant apps with Cosmos DB multi-master](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fOQoQnQqwwU)

Comment: Thanks! It's a B2B application, we'll not have more than 100 tenants very soon, and the tenants are bigger companies. The reason to get such isolation is twofold; synapse Analytics does not work well with multitenant DB account (data seperation on tenant level is very difficult). As such we'd go for this approach. It also allows us to give superusers direct read access to the account if needed, and it allows for easier backup solutions (current does not support inplace). All this with serverless btw, which makes creating containers not expensive anymore! I'll watch the link, thanks!

Comment: Makes sense. In that case I would keep tenant per account and run in separate application instances. You can also take advantage of AAD+RBAC support in Cosmos to further secure and isolate tenants.